# Re-writing my query to delete from a select statement

Tags: php, mysql

Here's my query which in theory would be what I want but I know that MySQL won't let you use the same table in the sub-select as in the delete:

```
DELETE FROM manifestPallet WHERE palletID IN 
( SELECT  manifestPallet.palletID 
            FROM manifestPallet
            LEFT JOIN manifestBox
            ON manifestPallet.palletID = manifestBox.palletID
            WHERE manifestBox.palletID IS NULL)
```

**I know I can do the select first, then loop through the results in my php script and do delete queries but I think there is probably a more elegant solution using pure MySQL.**

Extra info:
What the query does is delete pallets from a manifest that are empty. A user creates pallets then places boxes on them, if they create a pallet but don't put any boxes on it then the pallet needs to be removed when the manifest is closed.

Comment: Possible duplicate [MySQL Error 1093](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/45494/mysql-error-1093-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```sql
DELETE manifestPallet
FROM   manifestPallet LEFT JOIN manifestBox USING (palletID)
WHERE  manifestBox.palletID IS NULL
```

Comment: That worked! I had a feeling I was over-thinking my problem although I haven't had experience with keyword USING

Comment: @S.Mason: `a JOIN b USING (col1, col2)` is just shorthand for `a JOIN b ON a.col1 = b.col1 AND a.col2 = b.col2`.  The only difference is that, when doing `SELECT *`, the resultset contains one column only of each `col1` and `col2`.

Answer (score 0):

You simply need to specify on which tables to apply the DELETE.

Delete only the manifestPallet rows:

```
DELETE `manifestPallet` FROM `manifestPallet` LEFT JOIN `manifestBox` ....
```

Delete the manifestPallet and manifestBox rows:

```
DELETE `manifestPallet`, `manifestBox` FROM `manifestPallet` LEFT JOIN `manifestBox` ....
```

Delete only the manifestBox rows:

```
DELETE `manifestBox` FROM `manifestPallet` LEFT JOIN `manifestBox` ....
```

Answer (score 0):

```
DELETE FROM manifestPallet mp
WHERE NOT EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM manifestBox mbx
    WHERE mp.palletID = mbx.palletID
    );
```

Note: there is a semantic difference with the original query, since the `IN( subselect)` term removes NULLs (and duplicates).
This will probaly not cause differneces in the actual results, since the palletID is probably a NOT NULLable (primary) key.